# Access time strangeness

Tags: filesystems, ext4, timestamps

According to the `mount` man page,

> Access time is only updated if the previous access time was earlier than the current modify or change time.

However if I do this (ext4 with `relatime` option(*)):

```
> date +%T.%N ; dd if=/dev/random of=random.dat bs=1 count=4096 ; date +%T.%N ; stat random.dat 
18:52:00.616084761
4096+0 records in
4096+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB, 4.0 KiB) copied, 0.0319383 s, 128 kB/s
18:52:00.651183318
  File: random.dat
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 28313073    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      me)   Gid: ( 1000/      me)
Access: 2022-09-26 18:52:00.616297607 +0200
Modify: 2022-09-26 18:52:00.648297639 +0200
Change: 2022-09-26 18:52:00.648297639 +0200
 Birth: -
```

The access time seems to be stuck to the creation time, and if I rerun it (so now `random.dat` exists, and it is the same inode that is updated) I get:

```
> date +%T.%N ; dd if=/dev/random of=random.dat bs=1 count=4096 ; date +%T.%N ; stat random.dat 
18:52:43.014712313
4096+0 records in
4096+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB, 4.0 KiB) copied, 0.0633748 s, 64.6 kB/s
18:52:43.081174320
  File: random.dat
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd01h/64769d    Inode: 28313073    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      me)   Gid: ( 1000/      me)
Access: 2022-09-26 18:52:00.616297607 +0200
Modify: 2022-09-26 18:52:43.076338407 +0200
Change: 2022-09-26 18:52:43.076338407 +0200
 Birth: -
```

... where the access time hasn't changed at all despite a complete rewrite of the file contents.

What am I missing/misunderstanding? Shouldn't the access time be updated together with the modify and change ones?

(*) `/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)`

(**) Use of `dd if=/dev/random` for demo purposes (slow output)

Comment: You mentioned something about "creation time", where do you see that? Why should the access time change if you don't read the data? Rewriting the file's data does not access the data (note that the inode stays the same).

Comment: In the context of the three timestamps in the inode of a file, "access" means "read".  Writing bytes to a file does not itself change the access timestamp (atime), only the modification timestamp (mtime).  If you want to see the file's atmie update, open and read the file.  This can be as simple as `cat filename > /dev/null`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I expect the creation time to be a few milliseconds after the output of the first `date` (even if there is no timestamp defined for it in ext4). Also `access` includes `read`, but what else? (otherwise why isn't it named `read`?).

Comment: @xenoid `mmap(2)` accesses the file and isn't `read(2)`

Comment: @xenoid the names of the timestamps were created back in the 1980s or 1970s by researchers at Bell Labs.  They picked the names and behavior of the timestamps and since then Unix and Linux developers have kept the names and behaviors for backward compatibility.  Why did they choose the word "access" rather than "read"?  Hard to say.  But the fact remains that reading the file data is what changes the timestamp named `atime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not accessing the data blocks (only writing to them) then atime is not updated.  If you read the random.dat then the atime will get updated (as long as the relatime criteria is met).

you can see this for looking for calls to `file_accessed()` in the kernel:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/ext4/file.c

file_accessed will call the routines to update atime in the inode, and is only called in the read functions (and mmap).